# define dynamicUpdate property on application level for all entities?

Tags: hibernate

i was wondering if hibernate supports to define **dynamicUpdate=true** property on **application level** instead of defining it for each entity ?

Comment: I'd guess not and I wouldn't do it if it was possible, but +1 for the question ;)

Comment: Great question and I would do it if it were possible.  Hibernate can't handle DB side data defaults very well and this is a good work around for a utility application where a potential performance hit wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because dynamic-update/dynamic-insert are not optimized and well perform for all scenarios, It can create bottleneck in some cases, that's why hibernate guys did not give this option at application config level.

Comment: Can you tell me which cases dynamic-update/dynamic-insert will create bottleneck?

Comment: @Stony This might help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633250/how-dynamic-update-true-works-internally-in-hibernate