# configure Hibernate JPA to set dynamicUpdate=true by default for all entities?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'd like to setup all entities to use dynamic insert and dynamic update but avoid having to do so on per-class basis:

```
@javax.persistance.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert = true, dynamicUpdate = true)
public class User
```

is there a way to turn on dynamicInsert and update by default across entire entityfactory, so that I can omit the second @Entity declaration?

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605145/define-dynamicupdate-property-on-application-level-for-all-entities) it is not possible to do so because its implementation is not optimized.

So the only way is to apply it on every class you want this behavior, but be careful, it does have downsides. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404630/hibernate-dynamic-update-dynamic-insert-performance-effects).