# How to use hibernate @DynamicUpdate with spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data-jpa. I want update only one column.

My repository is;

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

my Service is;

```
public User save(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

my Entity;

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(true)
public class User implements Serializable {
    // column definitions, etc.
}
```

How can I update only one column in `User`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is due to your passing of an entirely new `User` entity hence Hibernate cannot use a cached version that has been already fetched from database and decide which columns to update dynamically.

So, try to do the following to confirm the correct behaviour of [`@DynamicUpdate`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html);

In service;

```
@Transactional
public User save(User newUser) {
    User currentUser = userRepository.get(newUser.getId());
    // handle merging of updated columns onto currentUser manually or via some mapping tool
    currentUser.setName(newUser.getName());
    return userRepository.save(currentUser);
}
```

With the above logic, together with dynamic update annotation, you should be able to see the update of only name column, unless you have some audit enabled, or using `@Version`'ed column.

If the updated columns are always same, then it is better to use `updatable = false` for the columns that are not target for the update in their `@Column` definitions, for using `@DynamicUpdate` is very inefficient since it generates each sql anew, never utilizing cached sqls. But beware using this feature, since you will be unable to update these columns at all.

I don't recommend using `@Query` unless you have a case where native JPA/Hibernate is insufficient, but if you have a use-case to update a target set of columns only, it is the best choice, and the most efficient.

If the updated columns are many and can vary greatly, either define a manual mapping logic between `newUser` to the `currentUser`, or utilize some mapping tools such as [`Orika`](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika), I have a similar automated structure where hundreds of entities are patched through these mappers, allowing an extremely generic way to handle many CRUD operations.

Comment: I want to use dynamic update for update profile of user,if user has many fields then its difficult to set all the values.

Comment: @RaviDeveloper you don't need to set other fields, after you do a `repository.get()`, you will have the existing `User` from db, just update its `profile` column & do a `save()`, be aware all of this should be in a `@Transactional` method, as it is in my answer. With `@DynamicUpdate` it should work, and update only the changed column; `profile`

Comment: @RaviDeveloper but if this is a use-case, meaning, you will always update "only the profile of a User", then it is better to use a `@Query`, since `@DynamicUpdate` is comparatively slower, but should still be OK

Comment: @RaviDeveloper it should be annotated on your `Entity`, you use it correctly in your example, though no need to pass boolean value to it, since by default it is `true`. If it does not work, please show what kind of SQL is being executed with your current implementation, maybe there is another issue with hibernate config etc

Answer (score 23):

First of all I want to explain why `@DynamicUpdate` is not working for you. So I should notice how `@DynamicUpdate` works:

> The @DynamicUpdate annotation is used to specify
>   that the UPDATE SQL statement should be generated whenever an entity
>   is modified. By default, Hibernate uses a cached UPDATE statement that
>   sets all table columns. When the entity is annotated with the
>   @DynamicUpdate annotation, the PreparedStatement is going to include
>   only the columns whose values have been changed.([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633250/how-dynamic-update-true-works-internally-in-hibernate/42806660#42806660))

For example assume that `User` has a property called `name`.

So if for the first time you saved user with a defined name, now you are passing `null` as the value `@DynamicUpdate` will assume it as a change and trying to update name to `null`.

**First solution:**

As the first solution, if you want `@DynamicUpdate` works, first you should fill all other `User` properties with old values, then you can save it.

*Pros:* The generated SQL query just updates the property you want.

*Cons:* Hibernate has to generate the corresponding SQL string each time and there is thus a performance cost on the Hibernate side.

**Second solution:**

You can update `User` with custom query:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User SET name=(:name) WHERE id=(:id)")
public void updateName(@Param("name")String name, @Param("id")Long id);
```

**Third solution:**

As the last solution I can suggest you to use `updatable = false`. This will fill the property on the very first moment the entity inserted.

```
  @Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Instant createDate;
```