# MySQL trigger working through direct insert, but not when committing through Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, triggers

I have the following snippet that we use to persist an entity into our DB:

```java
private void singleStatusChange( Employee employee , OrderStatusType type , String comment , String classification ){
        try( CloseableEntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager() ){
            em.beginTransaction();
            OrderStatusChangeRequest orderStatusChangeRequest = new OrderStatusChangeRequest();
            orderStatusChangeRequest.setOrder( em.getEntityReferenceById( Order.class , this.getId() ) );
            orderStatusChangeRequest.setOrderStatusType( type );
            orderStatusChangeRequest.setEmployee( employee );
            orderStatusChangeRequest.setComment( comment );
            orderStatusChangeRequest.setClassification( classification );
            //When this entry is being persisted a BEFORE INSERT Trigger is activated and 1.- Check if status change is feasible, 2.- Expire all previous order statuses, 3.- Updates order lastHandledBy
            em.persist( orderStatusChangeRequest );
            em.commit();
        }catch ( Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new InvalidOrderStatusChangeException( e );
        }
    }
```

When this occurs, a trigger is fired on BEFORE INSERT that takes care of additional business logic for our app. Everything except one statement is completed, and Im not entirely sure why this is the case. This is our trigger:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`gofarma`@`%` TRIGGER OrderStatusChangeRequestsBeforeInsert
BEFORE INSERT
ON OrderStatusChangeRequests FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @IsNewStatusPossible FROM OrderStatusTypeFlows ostf WHERE ostf.`To` = NEW.Status AND ostf.`From` IS NULL ;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @IsPossible FROM OrderStatusTypeFlows ostf WHERE ostf.`To` = NEW.Status AND ostf.`From` = ( SELECT o.Status FROM Orders o WHERE o.ID = NEW.`Order` LIMIT 1 );

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @IsImpossible FROM OrderStatusTypeFlows ostf WHERE ostf.`To` = NEW.Status AND ostf.`NeverIfThisPresent` IN ( SELECT `OrderStatusType` FROM OrderHistoryEntries WHERE `Order` = NEW.`Order` ) ;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @IsAdmin FROM Employees e LEFT JOIN EmployeeRoles er ON e.ID = er.EmployeeID LEFT JOIN Roles r ON er.RoleID = r.ID
    WHERE r.IsAdmin AND e.ID = NEW.Employee;

    IF( ( ( @IsPossible = 0 AND @IsNewStatusPossible = 0 ) OR @IsImpossible > 0 ) AND @IsAdmin = 0 ) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345' set message_text='com.gofarma.olimpo.exceptions.InvalidOrderStatusChangeException';
    END IF;

    UPDATE OrderHistoryEntries os SET os.EffectiveTo = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE os.`Order` = NEW.`Order` AND os.EffectiveTo > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

    INSERT INTO OrderHistoryEntries
    (ID, Comment, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, OrderStatusType, PrescriptionAction, SystemFrom, SystemTo, `Type`, Employee, `Order`)
    VALUES(UUID(), NEW.Comment, current_timestamp(), '9999-12-31 23:59:59', CASE
        WHEN NEW.Status = 0 THEN 'NEW'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 1 THEN 'PACKED'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 2 THEN 'SENT'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 3 THEN 'COMPLETED'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 4 THEN 'CANCELED'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 5 THEN 'UNKNOWN'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 6 THEN 'COLLECTED'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 7 THEN 'DELIVERED'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 8 THEN 'PRECOMPLETED'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 9 THEN 'RESENT'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 10 THEN 'UNPAID'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 11 THEN 'UNDELIVERED'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 12 THEN 'PENDING'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 13 THEN 'WAITING_FOR_ADVANCE'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 14 THEN 'ADVANCE_PICKED'
        WHEN NEW.Status = 15 THEN 'ADVANCE_NOT_PICKED'
    END, NULL, current_timestamp(), '9999-12-31 23:59:59', 'ORDER_STATUS', NEW.Employee, NEW.`Order`);

    UPDATE Orders o SET o.LastHandledBy = NEW.Employee , o.Status = NEW.Status WHERE o.ID = NEW.`Order`;

    IF( NEW.Status IN ( 3 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 12 ) ) THEN
        UPDATE Trips t JOIN TripOrders ot ON ot.TripID = t.ID JOIN DriverShifts ds ON ds.Driver = t.Driver
        SET t.status = 1 , t.closeComment = NEW.Comment , t.arrivalTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , t.realEndTime = COALESCE( t.realEndTime , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) , ds.AvailableSince = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        WHERE ot.OrderID = NEW.`Order` AND t.Status = 0 AND !t.IsTransporter;
    END IF;

    IF( (SELECT `PrescriptionAction` FROM `Orders` `o` WHERE `o`.`ID` = NEW.`Order`) <> 0 AND NEW.`Status` = 8) THEN
        UPDATE `Orders` `o` SET `o`.`PrescriptionNumber` = (
            SELECT 
                COALESCE(MAX(`PrescriptionNumber`),0)+1
            FROM 
                Orders
            WHERE 
                `PrescriptionAction` = `o`.`PrescriptionAction`
            AND
                `Branch` = `o`.`Branch`
            GROUP BY `Branch`) WHERE `o`.`ID` = NEW.`Order`;
    END IF;
END
```

The bit that does not execute properly is the following:

```sql
    UPDATE Orders o SET o.LastHandledBy = NEW.Employee , o.Status = NEW.Status WHERE o.ID = NEW.`Order`;
```

Everything else gets Inserted and updated. However, this statement does not execute at all. This only happens whenever we persist an entity through Hibernate, if we were to run a query to insert a new entry into our OrderStatusChangeRequest table, everything runs as expected. Is there something we are missing? Our hibernate.cfg.xml file contains the following:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">500</property>
        <!--<property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>-->
        <!--<property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>-->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect.storage_engine">innodb</property>
        <!--<property name="connection.release_mode">ON_CLOSE</property>-->
        <!--<property name="show_sql">true</property>-->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->

        <property name="hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold">30000</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

As additional info, CloseableEntityManager is just a wrapper for EntityManager that implements Autocloseable:

```java
    public CloseableEntityManager beginTransaction() {
        if (this.getTransaction().isActive()) return this;
        this.getTransaction().begin();
        return this;
    }

    public void commit() {
        this.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        logger.debug( String.format("Entity Manager %s close call",this.id) );
        if( this.entityManager == null ) return;
        boolean isActive = this.entityManager.getTransaction().isActive();
        if( isActive || readOnly ){
            logger.debug( String.format("Entity Manager %s transaction was active, rolling back",this.id) );
            this.entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        this.entityManager.close();
    }
```

Comment: Trigger cannot not fire, and it cannot be disabled. Check (create some service table and save ALL trigger firings and new record field values into it) - it is possible that Hibernate creates "abstract" record and then sets the specified values by a lot of UPDATE queries...

Comment: Do you maybe save the `order`-entity too? Since you, at least in this code snippet, do not update/refresh the value in the order-entity, the next write of the order-entity might overwrite the changes done by the trigger with the old values of the entity.

Comment: @Solarflare We do merge our Order entity, but we dont modify the Status(Which is an Enum) property at any point. Would this still cause issues with changes being overwritten?

Comment: @Akina The trigger does fire, every statement except the one pointed out seems to work. Im opting that it is something related to the entity's field being merged, but it does not happen anywhere.

Comment: This would depend on your settings (see e.g. [`@DynamicUpdate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42806660)). You may want to mirror what your trigger does to the order entity in your singleStatusChange-function and/or flush/refresh before/after it runs, depending on the rest of your application/other external sources of database changes/...

Comment: Using @DynamicUpdate worked!! That was exactly what was happening, thank you dearly @Solarflare!

Comment: Glad you could identify the problem, but be aware that your entity will still be out of date (and e.g. might induce other side effects in code that relied on full row updates)! E.g. if you use the status (just for read) in your app before a refresh, it will still have the old value (and a status column sounds like it might be used in business logic). You may have to test it properly, it is not trivial to make your app support external changes to your database. As mentioned, another way would be to (manually) update your order entity in your function (and/or not do it in your trigger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by a comment on the question, using @DynamicUpdate worked in my case.